# Formulário fixo passa por cima do menu

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Possuo uma aplicação onde tenho um menu normal no topo da página, e logo abaixo dele um formulário, onde esse formulário tem que ser fixo, de uma forma que quando eu role a página para baixo, esse formulário fique no topo da página, e o resto da página vá correndo por trás dele.

Meu problema está em deixar esse formulário da forma que preciso. Coloco a propriedade `position: fixed`, ele fica fixo, mas ou por cima do menu, ou totalmente desposionado na tela, e também pelo fato que vou usar essa mesma aplicação no celular, estou meio perdido em como fazer.

Comment: O menu será fixo no topo tambem? O form deve somente passar por baixo do menu?

Comment: @oOAkiraOo. Minha ideia inicial é o menu não ser fixo e quando eu subir a pagina, esse form ficar fixo no topo, mas se for o caso, deixo o menu fixo tbm sem problemas.

Comment: para colocar ele por cima, use no CSS: `z-index: 1000;`

Comment: Se a resposta abaixo não for a solução, por favor confira: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), este guia ajuda você a conseguir a resposta mais exata possível para resolver o problema.

Answer (score 3):

O elemento pai do `form` deve estar:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 99999; /* Pra Garantir */
```

Answer (score 2):

Caso o menu seja no topo, utilize uma margem do *top* para garantir que não fique sobre o menu, `margin-top: 150px` e utilize a propriedade `z-index: 999` para garantir que fique sobre os elementos de forma fixa.

CSS:

```
form{
     position: fixed;
     margin-top: 100px; // distancia do top
     right: 0;
     z-index: 9999;
}
```